# C# AnchorStyles for datagridview gives incorrect size after minimazing form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, size

I have two DataGridViews on my Form, for both AnchorStyle is used.
After window is minimized - second grid has incorrect size.
I do not know why? I do not chnge it in code.

```
    this.dgvTable.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
    | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
    // first dgv works fine

   // second dgv changes its height by itself after window minimazing!
   this.dgvProps.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)));
   this.dgvProps.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(440, 35);
   this.dgvProps.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(315, 310);
   dgvProps.RowHeadersVisible = true;
   dgvProps.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.AutoSizeToAllHeaders;
   dgvProps.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells;
   dgvProps.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter | DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnKeystroke;
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you mean by incorrect size? Kindly upload an image

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/O1ibu.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right answer is:

```
this.dgvProps.Anchor = 
System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top    | 
System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | 
System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right;
```

+function, that moves second datagrid and third button properly

```
protected override void OnResize (EventArgs e);
```

And everything works fine. Magic!